# Volume Control in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to make the max volume notice voice when user take a photo or start to record a video.
Is it possible and not be rejected by appStore??

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It might be a language-barrier issue but I'm honestly not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Celestial.framework` has an `AVSystemController` class that lets you get and set the current volume. Unfortunately it is a private class so Apple won't accept it in AppStore submission

Instead，you can show the volume slider to set it by user.

Like this:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds] autorelease];
[window addSubview:volumeView]; 
[volumeView sizeToFit];
```